# Importing json2xml library gives invalid syntax error

Tags: python

I am trying to import the following library:

```
import json2xml
from json2xml.utils import readfromstring
```

However, when I execute the second line I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\denis\Desktop\Pazaruvaj Upload\Pazaruvaj_Part1_Test.py", line 12, in <module>
    from json2xml.utils import readfromurl, readfromstring, readfromjson
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\json2xml\utils.py", line 19
    def readfromjson(filename: str) -> dict:
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Couldn't find anything online about this issue.

*Note I don't write `from json2xml import json2xml` because it gives the same error*

Answer (score 1):

According to https://pypi.org/project/json2xml/, json2xml is not compatible with Python2.

Python2 is deprecated, please update to Python3. Then this library should work.

Comment: Thank you! I did not think to check that.